# gitlab/codeceptjs tests were working fine yesterday now they can't even start

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, puppeteer, codeceptjs

months ago I made some tests on gitlab using codeceptjs/puppeteer. I was having 0 issues with the tests. this morning I woke up and every single test on every single app is failing before the apps even begin. none of the tests have been updated in 4+ weeks. they were running fine all on their own until now.

Now I get this error every single time before the first test even starts

```
`example -- user inserts text and html macro :heavy_multiplication_x: "before each" hook: codeceptjs.before for "user inserts text and html macro" in 13ms Error: Failed to launch the browser process!`
```

I have no idea what is causing this. I did some googling and all previous issues say that adding `"args": ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]` to the config will solve this problem but I already had that in my config file. it's been in my config file for months now. not sure what changed between last night and tonight. this is my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
`image: node:latest 


all_tests:
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl && rm -rf /src/*.deb
    - npm install
    - npm i codeceptjs-puppeteer
    - npm i codeceptjs puppeteer
    - ln -sf ./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs /usr/local/bin/codeceptjs
    - npm i --save arrify
    - ./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs run --steps


cache:
  paths:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs

after_script:
    - echo "Cleaning up"
    - rm -rf "%CACHE_PATH%/%CI_PIPELINE_ID%" 
`
```

months ago I pulled that from a repo on gitlab that had working puppeteer tests since I couldn't figure out how to build a properly working one. codeceptjs/puppeteer has a config file here are the contents

```
`exports.config = {
  tests: './tests/test_test.js',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    Puppeteer: {
      url: 'http://localhost',
      show: false,
      chrome: {
          "args": ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
      }
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js',
    login: './pages/login.js',
    confluence: './pages/confluence.js',
    editor: './pages/editor.js',
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'cloud ME user'
};`
```

so yeah that config was working fine for me for months until last night when all of a sudden it failed. everything I read says I need to specify that chrome is headless but I already tried that. I tried that months ago. anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Is your project public by any chance?  I'd like to see if I can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build config is using `node:latest` as the base image. Apparently, that has been changed yesterday (see [the README.md of node docker repository](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/commit/e3fc630cd437d8d445aa3401f1d87e93f9e50935#diff-36c4536996ca5615dcf9911f068786dc) from version 13 to 14.

You could try downgrading the node image back to version 13:

```
image: node:13
```

Or even something more specific according to your needs.